# Select documents which have a specific number of items of nested documents

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nested, nest

I have the structure (events are nested documents):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "<date 1>"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "<date 2>"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "date": "<date 3>"
    }
  ]
}
...
```

Using Elasticsearch.Net and NEST how to make a query which selects the documents which have events more than a specific number?

Comment: The JSON you have shared, is for one document in ElasticSearch? Can you share your index definition in ElasticSearch?

Comment: Updating a single object in the `"events"` array will require indexing of the whole object, whether passed in as input, or on the server side in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Note script are slow, if you have a lots of documents it s would be better to set a field = number of events and request on it.

```
QueryContainer filterContainer = null;
    filterContainer &= Query<YOURTYPE>.Script(s =>
                    s.Inline("params._source.events.size() > YOURNUMBER"));

    Client.Search<YOURTYPE>(s => s
                                .MatchAll()
                                .Size(10000)
                                .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(filterContainer )))
```

Comment: The nested list of events is updatable. The idea is to update events without updating a version of its parent document.

Comment: Add a field in events wont really help you, of couse you could add an index (1,2,3...) on each events, and retrieve the max index (or store events size in all event item), or add a first event item containing the events - 1 size...All of these solution are really dirty. Why you cant add a field on parent (you dont have to reindex by adding a new field, maybe you build parent documents and events with 2 separated tools?)

Comment: We have EventsCount field in a current verions of the app. But when the field changes, a version of the document changes too. Updating a version of the document invokes a heavy action. However, we don't need to execute the action when the number of events changes. Thus, we have decided to try to store a list of events which we could change without changing the version of the parent document.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't update `events` via a script I would just keep actual count of events within a parent document. That would make the search part easier and much more efficient.

Document schema:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EventsCount => Events?.Count ?? 0;
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and query:

```
_elasticClient.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(t => t.Field(f => f.EventsCount).Value(10))));
```